# (Python) Solving an equation with an unknown number, find that number with an equation

Tags: python

I making a code (for fun and practice) to balance chemical equations. I want to try and balance `N + A` so it `= Z`

```
N = 2
A = 2
Z = 6
if N + A != Z:
print('X')
balancer = ???
```

The balancer should be 3 so that if I make an equation e.g (balancer x N) + A = Z it would be true. How would I make the balancer be three with out directly inputing it.

Thanks :)

Comment: For, is `if N and A != Z` really what you want here? You're testing that `N` is not zero, and `A` is not the same as `Z`, which is of course true, but it's not at all the same as testing whether `N + A` is not the same as `Z`.

Comment: You should be using the mathematical operator, `+`, not logical operator `and`.

Comment: Meanwhile, are you looking for a way to just enter some equations and have Python work out `balancer` for you, or are you looking at how to write the equation to find `balancer` manually? For the former, you need some kind of algebra library, like `SymPy`. For the latter, you need to do the algebra by hand (take `(balancer * N) + A = Z`, solve for `balancer` in terms of `N, A, Z`), and then converting that to code is trivial.

Comment: @abarnert Im looking for python to figure it out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to do the basic algebra by hand:

```
(balancer * N) + A = Z
(balancer * N) = Z - A # subtract A from both sides
balancer = (Z - A) / N # divide both sides by N
```

… and then it's trivial to turn that into code—that last line actually *is* the valid Python code, with no changes.

---

Or, if you want Python to do this for you, just by specifying `(balancer * N) + A = Z` as an equation… Python doesn't have anything built in to do that, but there are algebra libraries like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/) to do.

You'll really want to work through the whole tutorial, but briefly…

First, you have to first tell it that your variables are variables:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, solve, Eq
>>> A, N, Z, balancer = symbols('A N Z balancer')
```

Then, build an equation. The left side can just be `(balancer * N) + a` and `Z`, but you can't just put an `=` or `==` between them; you have to use `Eq`:

```
>>> equation = Eq((balancer * N) + A, Z)
```

Now you can substitute in the values for your variables:

```
>>> equation.subs(dict(N=2, A=2, Z=6))
Eq(2*balancer + 2, 6)
```

And finally, solve for valid solutions:

```
>>> solve(equation.subs(dict(N=2, A=2, Z=6))
[2]
```

Or, if you'd prefer to solve it algebraically and then substitute, instead of the other way around:

```
>>> solve(equation, 'balancer')
[(-A + Z)/N]
>>> [s.subs(dict(N=2, A=2, Z=6)) for s in solve(equation, 'balancer')]
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a condition to test whether the left side, `N + A`, is greater than or less than than the right side, `Z`. You could use `(N + A) - Z`, yielding `-2`, which tells you that you're missing two atoms. From there you'll need to write some logic to determine which atoms it is that you're missing.

With simple variables pointing to integers, there's no way to intuitively predict which atoms you'll need to add. Presumably you're working from an equation, though, so I'd suggest you look into a regex solution to that parse that. Something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.findall('(\d*)((?:[A-Z][a-z]?\d*)+)', '2CH4 + O2')
>>> for n, molecule in m:
...     print(n or 1, molecule)
... 
2 CH4
1 O2
```

And then parse the atoms similarly from there.